# "No Values to save" when initializing tf.train.Saver

Tags: tensorflow

I have a class DDPG that is a tensorflow neural network. When I add `self.saver = tf.train.Saver()` it reports an error

> "  File "C:\Users\Harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1131, in _build
>       raise ValueError("No variables to save")"

Here is the part of my code.

```
 def __init__(self, action_dimension, state_dimension):
    self.memory = np.zeros((MEMORY_CAPACITY, state_dimension*2+action_dimension+1), dtype = np.float32)
    self.memory_pointer = 0
    self.sess = tf.Session()
    self.action_dimension = action_dimension
    self.state_dimension = state_dimension
    # define state space as x * state dimension matrix
    self.current_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_dimension], 'current_state')
    self.next_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_dimension], 'next_state')  # same as above
    self.reward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'reward')
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

## Here is two functions I declared in this class.

```
    def save_model(self):
    path = self.saver.save(self.sess, "/saved_model/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % path)

def load_model(self):
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, "/saved_model/model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
```

I am wondering what I am doing is incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you didn't initialize your variables yet. if you run [tf global variables initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/global_variables) after declaring all your variables and before your 
`self.saver` you should be fine